# Copy Partial Table from one database to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to copy certain data (where state = 'TX', for example) from a table in one database on a remote server to another database on my server. The error I'm getting is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'. Expecting EDGE_TYPE or FILETABLE" right after the 'AS' keyword.

The table I'm copying from is huge and I don't have server space to copy the entire table, nor will I ever need it. I've found sites that show how to do this but for some reason they never work in SQL Server, even though they work in online sql queries (w3 schools: [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp#:~:text=the%20old%20table.-,Syntax,-CREATE%20TABLE%20new_table_name](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp#:%7E:text=the%20old%20table.-,Syntax,-CREATE%20TABLE%20new_table_name)).

Here is my code more or less:

```
CREATE TABLE [DB1].dbo.PartialData AS
SELECT [col1]
      ,[col2]
      ,[col3]
      ,[col4]
FROM [DB2].[dbo].[FullData]
WHERE [DB2].[dbo].[FullData].State = 'TX';
```

Comment: Best to avoid *w3fools.com* and use the documentation for your RDBMS - that syntax is not part of the t-sql syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, use `select.. into...`

```
SELECT col1
      ,col2
      ,col3
      ,col4
 INTO DB1.dbo.PartialData
 FROM DB2.dbo.FullData
WHERE State = 'TX';
```

Comment: Does it matter that these are on different servers and I have basic privileges on db2? Because I'm getting an error::: Invalid object name 'DB2' :::
after the 'FROM' keyword

Comment: It will work fine cross-database on the *same* server but not between different servers. There's nothing in your question about the databases being on physically different servers, that's a different answer; you'll need to create the target table and use *openrowset* or *linked servers*.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was implied when I said "I don't have server space to copy the entire table"

Comment: @tgoodell Ok - that could mean anything, no single drive with free space, filegroup size, logfile space, always best to be very explicit to get the most accurate answers; besides, your example syntax contains 3-part-names which can ONLY work on the one server.

Comment: Had to reconfigure some settings on remote server to allow for openrowset usage. Then used OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=[server2]...)

Answer (score 0):

Complexity is going to be setting up linked [servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

If you linked server hosting db1 to server for db2, you would query using a 4 part name:

```
insert [db2].[dbo].[PartialData]
select * from [server1].[db1].[dbo].[fullData]
```

You would insert to a 4 part name if you set up linked server in the opposite direction

```
insert [server2].[db2].[dbo].[PartialData]
select * from [db1].[dbo].[fullData]
```